# Open native iOS ring tone screen programmatically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am developing an alarm based iOS application where the user can set the alarm tune from ring tone menu. I am new to iOS so I do not know if that is possible or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to be able to change the alarm tone that the Apple-provided alarm app uses?

Nope.

Apple does not allow third party apps to muck around with the settings of their apps.

Comment: I think the OP is asking if they can set the tones of their own internal alarms from the device ringtone menu

Comment: ok..can you help me how can i open native ring tone screen? which is provided by apple in setting->sound->ringtone.

Comment: @user3140414 its not possible to open ring tone screen with native application.